# iOS NSXMLParser - Consistently Derive Image Source URL From XML Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rss, nsxmlparser

I'm working with RSS feeds in my app, specifically with Drudge Report's. I'm quite new to this sort of stuff, along with being new to using Xcode's `NSXMLParser`. Each feed apparently represents an article. Each feed is represented by the `<item></item>` tags.

Within these tags, there's a description of info enclosed by the `<description></description>` tags. In the description, some articles might have an image associated with that article, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

The part I highlighted is the image I need to get (specifically, the URL string). I'm able to derive the description each article as an `NSMutableString`, but how do I derive the image's URL when I parse the XML with NSXMLParser? The following is my code so far as to how I'm getting all of this done:

```
@interface ViewController () <NSXMLParserDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSMutableString *description;
    NSString *element;
}
.
.(other code)
.
#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item        = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title       = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link        = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        description = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"feedburner:origLink"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [description appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        NSString *filteredTitle = [title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *filteredLink = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (![filteredLink containsString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/"]) {
            [item setObject:filteredTitle forKey:@"title"];
            [item setObject:filteredLink forKey:@"link"];
            [item setObject:description forKey:@"description"];

            [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

***PROGRESS***

So far, I added the following in my `didEndElement` method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        NSString *filteredTitle = [title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *filteredLink = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (![filteredLink containsString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/"]) {
            [item setObject:filteredTitle forKey:@"title"];
            [item setObject:filteredLink forKey:@"link"];
            [item setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
            if ([description rangeOfString:@"img style"].location != NSNotFound)
            {

            }

            [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I know that the description has the `img style` string in it, I need to get the `src="whateverImageURL"`. How do I use a regular expression to get the first occurrence of this image URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've managed to solve my problem. I just needed a little practice with using `NSRange`. The idea is, in my case, that when I have a description that has the `NSString` "img style" in it, I know for a fact that I need the first "src="whateverImageURL" string that I can get. I do this in the following code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        NSString *filteredTitle = [title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *filteredLink = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (![filteredLink containsString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/"]) {
            [item setObject:filteredTitle forKey:@"title"];
            [item setObject:filteredLink forKey:@"link"];
            [item setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
            if ([description rangeOfString:@"img style"].location != NSNotFound) {
                NSString *finalImageURL;
                NSRange startRange = [description rangeOfString:@"src=\""];
                finalImageURL = [description substringFromIndex:startRange.location];
                finalImageURL = [finalImageURL substringFromIndex:startRange.length];
                NSRange endRange = [finalImageURL rangeOfString:@"\""];
                finalImageURL = [finalImageURL substringToIndex:endRange.location];
            }

            [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'l have to do the following in ur

> foundCharacters: method.

```
   else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]) 
{
        [description appendString:string];
if ([description rangeOfString:@"img"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange firstRange = [previewImage rangeOfString:@"src="];
        NSRange endRange = [[previewImage substringFromIndex:firstRange.location] rangeOfString:@" width=\""];
        NSString *finalLink = [[NSString alloc] init];
        finalLink = [previewImage substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(firstRange.location, endRange.location)];
        NSString *match = @"src=\"";
        NSString *postMatch;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:finalLink];
        [scanner scanString:match intoString:nil];
        postMatch = [finalLink substringFromIndex:scanner.scanLocation];
        NSString *finalURL = [postMatch stringByAppendingString:@""];
        description = finalURL;
    }
    }
}
```

- Since in ur foundCharacters u are already getting the description tag
  u need to search for the text in ur description array where u append
  the string.
- that u can do by scanning the entire string then store the required
  substring in a variable...i.e ur URL link
- Use firstRange variable to set the range from where ull take the string
- and endrange variable to set the text till where u want the string to end (in ur case the url)

Here i m storing the URL in previewImage.

Hope it works for u good luck.....

Comment: What's the previewImage variable? I don't see it being initialized

Comment: just create and initialise one more NSMutableString in didStartElement method to store the link....
u can store it in description variable too.
but its better to have a different variable...

Comment: I almost got this working, but you put it in the wrong method. The correct place to do what I need is in the `didEndElement` method

Comment: i have it working fine for me in foundCharacters method... anyways if my answer was useful for u then accept it the answer after suggesting any changes(if required).. or upvote it thanks.
by the way it Enters 'didEndElement ' at the end of parsing... so i dont know how its working for u...

Comment: I'm sorry but your code isn't working on my end. It keeps crashing with an "index out of bounds" exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for sparking my interest of `NSRange`. After researching it, I was able to experiment and eventually solve my problem! I gave you an upvote :)

Comment: it wont work exactly as it is because every xml document will be slightly different and youll have to figure out on ur own... however the basic idea here is that u have got the target string and u need to extract the right substring from it. u might have to change the matchstrings.

Comment: The index out of bound error occurred because either your firstRange endRange or ur matchstring is not found the string contained by description.
just debug the code and ull get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement this protocol

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName forElement:(NSString *)elementName type:(nullable NSString *)type defaultValue:(nullable NSString *)defaultValue;
```

this allow you to get all attribute  for each element found.

Let me know if this help you :)

**UPDATE**

Here a code that find the url of first img found in a given string

```
 NSString *descriptionString = @"&lt;br&gt;&lt;tt&gt;&lt;font size=\"3\" color=\"blue\"&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;LIST: 10 Worst Winter Storms in Washington History...&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/tt&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;font face=\"Arial\" size=\"1\"&gt;&lt;i&gt;(Top headline, 3rd story, &lt;a href=\"http://www.nbcwashington.com/news/local/Ten-Worst-Storms-in-DC-History-365815301.html\"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;)&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;hr style=\"height: 1px; border-style: none; color: #666666; background-color: #666666;\"/&gt;&lt;font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\"&gt;Related stories:&lt;div class=\"related-links\" id=\"R:H1:S3\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.wunderground.com/US/DC/001.html#WIN\"&gt;BLIZZARD WARNING ISSUED FOR DC; BURBS UP TO 30\"...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://washington.cbslocal.com/2016/01/19/winter-is-finally-here-deep-freeze-and-snow-in-the-forecast/\"&gt;Mayor Requests Help From National Guard...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-news/snow-storm-travel-disruptions-aim-for-nyc-dc-boston-philadelphia-friday-saturday/54870622\"&gt;UPDATE...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.infowars.com/snowmaggedon2016-empty-store-shelves-as-panicked-shoppers-ransack-grocery-stores/\"&gt;Anxious Shoppers Ransack Grocery Stores...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://motherboard.vice.com/read/dark-web-users-are-worried-snowstorm-jonas-will-disrupt-their-deliveries\"&gt;Dark Web Users Fear Delivery Disruptions...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2016/01/21/heres-why-some-people-drop-dead-while-shoveling-snow/\"&gt;Cold weather, shoveling form heart attack 'perfect storm'...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=\"feedflare\"&gt;    &lt;a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?a=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:yIl2AUoC8zA\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?d=yIl2AUoC8zA\" border=\"0\"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?a=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:V_sGLiPBpWU\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?i=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:V_sGLiPBpWU\" border=\"0\"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?a=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:qj6IDK7rITs\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?d=qj6IDK7rITs\" border=\"0\"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?a=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:gIN9vFwOqvQ\"&gt;&lt;img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/DrudgeReportFeed?i=Mtf4NlmV8XU:vDGXzaysxPw:gIN9vFwOqvQ\" border=\"0\"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/DrudgeReportFeed/~4/Mtf4NlmV8XU\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\" alt=\"\"/&gt";
NSString *stringWithoutWhiteSpace = [descriptionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSInteger srcLocation = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace rangeOfString:@"src="].location;
if ( srcLocation!= NSNotFound) {
    NSString *firstSrcImg = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace substringFromIndex:srcLocation];
    NSArray *componment = [firstSrcImg componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    NSString *url = componment[1];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}
```

i invite you to try it and tell me if it respond to your question ...
i can give another code that return all img urls :)

**SECOND UPDATE**
For the example i have done here a method that you can use:

```
- (NSString*) getNextURLFromString:(NSString*) str withURLTag:(NSString*) urlTag{
NSString *stringWithoutWhiteSpace = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSInteger srcLocation = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace rangeOfString:urlTag].location;
if ( srcLocation!= NSNotFound) {
    NSString *firstSrcImg = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace substringFromIndex:srcLocation];
    NSArray *componment = [firstSrcImg componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    NSString *url = componment[1];
    return url;
}
return nil;
}
```

for the `urlTag` param put `@"src="` 
and for the `str` param put the description tag value

**UPDATE N° 3**

here a method that return all images url

```
- (NSArray*) getAllURLFromString:(NSString*) str withURLTag:(NSString*) urlTag{
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *stringWithoutWhiteSpace = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSInteger srcLocation = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace rangeOfString:urlTag].location;
if ( srcLocation!= NSNotFound) {
    NSString *firstSrcImg = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace substringFromIndex:srcLocation];
    NSArray *componment = [firstSrcImg componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    if ([componment count]>1) {
        NSString *url = componment[1];
        [result addObject:url];

        NSArray *nextComponent = [stringWithoutWhiteSpace componentsSeparatedByString:url];
        if ([nextComponent count]>1) {
            [result addObjectsFromArray:[self getAllURLFromString:nextComponent[1] withURLTag:urlTag]];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
return result;
}
```

for the `urlTag` param put `@"src="`

and for the `str` param put the description tag value

Comment: Sorry, but this method was never executed whenever I parsed the XML

Comment: can you give me the url of your RSS or just the description tag so i can do some test.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me for the specific use case of finding the "img style" string. Your solution was very close though. I have already solved my problem and posted my own answer. I have to wait like 10 hours to accept it though. Thanks for your time in trying to help me! I gave you an upvote because your answer was pretty close to my solution.